# How do I get TFS 2013 Build definition to zip the build output?

Tags: powershell, tfs, msbuild

I am using VS2013 and TFS2013.  In TFS, I am using the new "default" TfvcTemplate12.xaml template.

In my build definition, in the Test-> Post-Build Script Arguments (or Path if I have to save the command in a file), what PowerShell script do I enter to get it to Zip the entire build output and drop that zip file onto a share drive?  I want to avoid manipulating the XAML workflow.

I know the basic PS script to zip a folder is....

`Get-Childitem C:\source -Recurse | Write-Zip -IncludeEmptyDirectories -OutputPath C:\stage\zomeZipFile.zip`

But I don't know if this is the right approach, and if so, what to replace the source and stage parameters with.

Our code migration system requires us to have 1 ZIP file with everything in it for deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the PowerShell to the post-test script location.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx

MSDN had a comprehensive list of the cracks that you have access to when it is executing.

Comment: Access the variables using `$env:`.  The drop location would be `$env:TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION` for example